# Single header file for exporting and C and C++ APIs

Tags: c++, c

I have a set of C++ classes whose objects are managed in a plain C++ file. For this file, I have a header file. Some of the APIs I want to access from C module and some from C++ module. Any suggestions how can I achieve this?

For trying out the approach I wrote following files.

My main class and its implementation(myclass.h and myclass.cpp):

**myclass.h**

```
#ifndef _MY_CLASS_H
#define _MY_CLASS_H

#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();

        void setServer(std::string url);
        void printServer();
    private:
        std::string serverURL;
};

#endif
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass()
         :serverURL("")
{
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

void MyClass::setServer(std::string url)
{
    serverURL = url;
}

void MyClass::printServer()
{
    if (serverURL == "") {
        std::cout << "Server URL is empty\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Server URL : " << serverURL << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now a wrapper is written which uses the above class. Aim is to expose two APIs init() and uninit() to C module and rest two for C++ module.

**wrappe.h**

```
#ifndef _WRAPPER_H
#define _WRAPPER_H

#include<string>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif // __cplusplus
// APIs that are exposed to C module(s)
void init();
void uninit();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif // __cplusplus

// C++ APIs exposed to C++ modules
#ifdef __cplusplus
void setServer(std::string url);
void printS();
#endif // __cplusplus

#endif // _WRAPPER_H
```

**wrapper.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h"

static MyClass *myClass = 0;

void init()
{
    myClass = new MyClass();
}

void uninit()
{
    if (myClass != 0) {
        delete myClass;
    }
}

void setServer(std::string url)
{
    myClass->setServer(url);
}

void printS()
{
    if (myClass != 0) {
        myClass->printServer();
    }
}
```

Here are the C module files which access the C APIs.

**backend.h**

```
#ifndef _BACKEND_H
#define _BACKEND_H

#ifndef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void backend_init();
void backend_uninit();

#ifndef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

**backend.c**

```
#include "wrapper.h"
#include "backend.h"

void backend_init()
{
    init();
}

void backend_uninit()
{
    uninit();
}
```

Here are the C++ module files which call the API of wrapper.h

**guiuser.h**

```
ifndef _GUIUSER_H
#define _GUIUSER_H

void gui1();
void gui2();

#endif
```

**guiuser.cpp**

```
#include "wrapper.h"

void gui1()
{
    setServer("localhost");
}

void gui2()
{
    printS();
}
```

Here is the main file which calls the module APIs.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "guiuser.h"
#include "backend.h"
#include "wrapper.h"

int main()
{
    backend_init();
    gui1();
    gui2();
    backend_uninit();
}
```

Compilation fails for backend.c
wrapper.h:4:17: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Should I break wrapper.h into two? One to include in backend and one to include in guiuser?

Any other suggestions on the design?

Comment: Take a closer look at where you put that `#include<string>`.

Comment: compiler gcc or g++ ?

Comment: molbdnilo - Your hint was helpful and R Sahu provided the exact solution to the mistake. Apart from this, there was another mistake in wrapper.cpp. I had to include wrapper.h in wrapper.cpp. With these two changes, I could compile and link the program successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<string>` is a C++ only header. Surround the `#include <string>` line with the same kind of preprocessor logic that you use for `setServer`.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <string>
#endif
```